# Dynamically creating class objects during runtime in C++

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I'm trying to create objects during runtime.  I have an unspecified number of objects to create and I am completely lost.  I have been told to use pointers for doing this, but I' not sure where to go even using a pointer.

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Consumer
{
public:
    int idNum;
    string info;
    int maxHours;
    Consumer(int, string, int);
    void display();
    void newCons();
};

Consumer::Consumer()
{
    idNum = id;
    info = in ;
    maxHours = hrs;
}

void Consumer::newCons()
{
    int idn;
    string npa;
    int mhrs;
    cout << "Please input the consumer's ID number." << endl;
    cin >> idn;
    cout << "Please input the consumer's full name, phone number, and address." << endl;
    cout << "Do not press enter until you have entered all three." << endl;
    cin >> npa;
    cout << "Please input the max number of hours the consumer spends purchasing products each week." << endl;
    cin >> mhrs;

    Consumer anotherCons(idn, npa, mhrs);

    return;
}

void Consumer::display()
{
    return;
}

int main()
{
    int i, howMany;
    Consumer* anotherCons;
    anotherCons = new Consumer();

    anotherCons->newCons();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: hint: you construct's signature doesn't match

Comment: Thanks, it's from all of the playing around, haven't cleaned the testing parts out.

Comment: Is this your real code? It shouldn't compile..

Comment: It doesn't.  I'm very new in programming.  These are test projects that I am trying to get working.  It doesn't compile.  I didn't fix all the testing screw ups before submitting.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::vector`: (`#include <vector>`)

```
vector<Consumer> list;
for(int i = 0; i < num_you_want_to_create; ++i){
    Consumer c; //declare an object of type consumer, if it doesn't work, try:
    //Consumer c(1, "test", 1);
    list.push_back(c); //creates a new consumer
}
```

Comment: (64): error C2512: 'Consumer' : no appropriate default constructor available

Comment: Yes thats because you defined a default constructor but didn't declare it in your class

Comment: Isn't the constructor Consumer?  I changed it to:

Comment: public:
      int idNum;
      string info;
      int maxHours;
      Consumer(int, string, int);
      void display();
      void newCons();  
    };

      Consumer::Consumer(int id, string in, int hrs)
 {
    idNum = id;
    info = in;
    maxHours = hrs;
 }

Comment: With the three data members, it worked.  How would I access it to display the information though?

Answer (score 0):

```
anotherCons = new Consumer();
//            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Here you're calling the default-constructor of your `Customer` class. You've defined one for your class but it isn't forward-declared (prototyped in the class body). You have one constructor defined as:

```
Customer(int, string, int);
```

but this serves a completely different constructor. You'll need to have a prototype of a default-constructor as well as a specialized constructor:

```
Customer();
Customer(int, string, int);
```

Moreover, in your `newCons` method, you call the parameratized constructor above. This will again cause an error because you have not defined the constructor anywhere in the code you gave us. Your constructor should be defined like this:

```
Customer::Customer(int id, string in, int hrs)
    : idNum(id), info(in), maxHours(hrs)
{ }
```

Here we're using the *member-initializer* list. You could have also used this with the default-constructor as well.

---

What @awesomeyi said was correct, you can use a `std::vector` to dynamically add objects at runtime. It's better than manually allocating a deallocating the memory as it is done manually by the constructors/destructors of the vector.

Furthermore, I think your `newCons` function should be changed to:

```
static Consumer newCons();
```

I added `static Consumer` to the return type and got rid of `void`. Why did I do this? Well, I am returning `Consumer` because it fits the semantics of the function - you want to create a new `Consumer` object, but what do you do with it when you've created it? Well, you have to get the object back to the caller so they can use it, so I decided it's better to return a new one. On the last line you would do:

```
Consumer anotherCons(idn, npa, mhrs);
return anotherCons;
```

or

```
return Consumer(idn, npa, mhrs);
```

This is great so far. Here's what the body of `main` looks like:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<Consumer> v;
    v.push_back(Consumer());

    v.at(0) = Consumer::newCons();
}
```

<sub>This is just an example of `main`. Your real code could be anything.</sub>

Personally, I think it's better to define an extractor for a `Consumer` object as it fits the feel for the standard IOStreams library. For instance:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Consumer& c)
{
    c = Consumer::newCons(is);
    return is;
}
```

And this also necessitates having `Consumer::newCons` take a parameter:

```
static Consumer newCons(std::istream& is)
```

and using `is` in place of `cin`.

And now:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<Consumer> v;

    Consumer c;
    std::cin >> c;

    v.push_back(c);
}
```